moment.js returning random date and utc time
I am using Moment.js in a project to process date & time entered by user, and every time it returns a random date along with UTC time. Below is the code for extracting values into variables:
const formattedEventDate = moment(values.eventDate, "Do-MM-YYYY").toISOString();
const formattedEventTime = moment(values.eventTime, "HH:mm:ss").toISOString();

If user enters 2024-04-24 & 11:30, it will return random datetime values such as, eventDate: 2013-08-05 18:30:00.000, eventTime: 2013-08-05 06:00:00.000
I tried tweaking the format, and using moment-timezone's tz() function after setting up tz.setDefault() but still these random values are being returned.
What I want is, eventDate: 2024-04-24 and eventTime: 11:30, should I change anything while declaring these variables or should I convert them to some other ISO format?

Ensure values.eventDate follows the format "YYYY-MM-DD" and values.eventTime follows "HH:mm".
const formattedEventDate = moment(values.eventDate, "YYYY-MM-DD").toISOString();
const formattedEventTime = moment(values.eventTime, "HH:mm").toISOString();

